# How to contribute to flink?

Tags: apache-flink

still not sure which branch I should check out to make a PR.
Looking at 1.10 vs master there are big differences - lots of refactoring on master and a load of classes now gone (or renamed?).

Where should one be making a contribution? 
Should I take a branch off 1.10 or Master?

Comment: https://flink.apache.org/contributing/how-to-contribute.html in case it helps

Comment: always the master.